# I am writing a letter. He is writing a letter

Tags: conjunctions

I am writing a letter. He is writing a letter (as well as) . Here using conjuction "as well as", what will be correct answer??? Please tell me

Answer (score 2):

To conjoin the two sentences with "as well as", you could say any of these, but they all have big problems:

> (1) I as well as he is writing a letter.
> (2) I am writing a letter as well as he.
> (3) I am writing a letter as well as he is.

The problem with (1) is that it's so awkward to have "is" as the verb when the subject is "I". Replacing "is" with "am" or "are" sounds just as bad.

Sentences (2) and (3) can have the meaning you want, but since "well" is also an adverb that roughly means "good", most people would understand something like, "*We are both writing letters, and my letter writing is as good as his letter writing.*"

The closest way to conjoin those sentences is with "as well" (no second "as"):

> I am writing as letter and he is as well.

This sentence is correct, natural, and has exactly the meaning you want.

Comment: This types of explanations should be encouraged in answes. Usually we want to use a construct like *as well as* in a particular situation. We think somehow we can use in the situation. Just saying don't use that use this wouldn't helpful to learners. Better show some of the possible ways of using that construct in the situation and explain why such usages would lead to ambiguity or awkwardness.

Answer (score 1):

You could say "He is writing a letter as well".

You don't use "as well as" at the end of the sentence.  You can use "as well".